# Include Property In Object Relationship in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

How can I return all the fields regarding to a relation in Ember ?
I'm using JSONAPI but only ID and type are on the relation.

[image]

Comment: that's hard to answer: What does the server-response look like? What are the model-definitions? What have you tried to get anything (what??) else but the type of the model 'judge' and what errors did you get? Other properties are usually "hidden" behind `model.get('property')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you get this setup if the values you are after are in the `included` key further down in the payload. If you aren’t seeing that, sending a `?include=judge` as part of your GET request should get you the value in the overall response from the server ...